# ' and ^t to the left of a letter

Tags: math-mode, spacing, formatting, equations

There are times where I want, say, a superscript `$t$` to the left of another letter to denote, say, the transpose of a matrix. Or, I might want to decorate a letter on the left with a prime, `$'$`, because the right side is busy being decorated by another letter. Right now I use, `$\left.^t M\right.$` and `$\left.'E^r\right.$` which is inadequate because it introduces white spaces. How do I deal with this?

Comment: `mathtools` provides the `\prescript` macro.

Comment: That was way less of a hassle than feared. Thanks!

Comment: Apparently, writing `{}'` or `{}^t` also works.

Comment: Yes, if the symbol to the right has “normal” height.

Comment: @Werner: This is definitely a duplicate.